# GWT RootPanel not interacting

Tags: gwt, cordova

I have created Login Class:

```
public class LoginPage extends VerticalPanel implements ClickHandler {

ApplicationMethods appMthd;
private RootPanel rootPanel;
TextBox txtUserEmail;
PasswordTextBox txtPassword;

Button btnLogin;

String strEmail, strPass;

public LoginPage(ApplicationMethods appMthd) {

    this.appMthd = appMthd;

    rootPanel = RootPanel.get();
    rootPanel.setSize("320", "480");

    btnLogin = new Button("Login");
    btnLogin.setText("Login");
    rootPanel.add(btnLogin, 224, 256);
    btnLogin.setSize("79px", "35px");
    btnLogin.addClickHandler(this);


    txtUserEmail = new TextBox();
    rootPanel.add(txtUserEmail, 36, 161);
    txtUserEmail.setSize("240px", "20px");


    txtPassword = new PasswordTextBox();
    rootPanel.add(txtPassword, 36, 207);
    txtPassword.setSize("240px", "20px");
    }

@Override
public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(event.getSource() == btnLogin)
    {
        strEmail = txtUserEmail.getText().toString();
        strPass = txtPassword.getText().toString();

        appMthd.onLogin(strEmail, strPass);
    }
    else
    {
        Window.alert("Coming Soon..!!");
    }
}
```

}

But I can't access any textbox or click on button.
Because Parent class is RootPanel.

If I am using :

```
add(txtUserEmail);
    add(txtPassword);
    add(btnReg);
    add(btnLogin);
    btnLogin.addClickHandler(this);
```

Then, it is accessible. In this, parent class is VerticalPanel.

So, how can I resolve this problem for RootPanel.?

Please help me for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i run your code (on ie9) and it works fine, i could click on the textfields and button, i think though that you should add the widgets on the vertical panel, and then add the vertical panel on the RootPanel, The LoginPage extends verticalPanel after all

Comment: Can you please tell me sample code for "you should add the widgets on the vertical panel, and then add the vertical panel on the RootPanel"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use VerticalPanel you can't specify the x,y
You can of course extend AbsolutePanel if you want to specify x,y 
but since you're programming for mobile, that's a good thing.

If you want to create mobile applications with phonegap and gwt

you should check the [mgwt](http://www.m-gwt.com/) and [hello world mgwt](http://code.google.com/p/mgwt/wiki/HelloWorldExample)

```
public LoginPage() {

    rootPanel = RootPanel.get();
    rootPanel.setSize("320", "480");
    rootPanel.add(this);

    btnLogin = new Button("Login");
    btnLogin.setText("Login");
    add(btnLogin);
    btnLogin.setSize("79px", "35px");
    btnLogin.addClickHandler(this);

    txtUserEmail = new TextBox();
    add(txtUserEmail);
    txtUserEmail.setSize("240px", "20px");

    txtPassword = new PasswordTextBox();
    add(txtPassword);
    txtPassword.setSize("240px", "20px");
}
```